# getting Fetch response data

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm using the chrome devTools to mirror a webRequest. Looking at the network request, there is some JSON data in the response that I want to get access to

Right click --> Copy as fetch -->

```
fetch(
    "https://www.url.com/service.svc?action=FindConversation&ID=-40&AC=1",
    {
        "credentials":"include",
        "headers":{
            "accept":"*/*",
            "accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "action":"FindConversation",
            "content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            "actionid":"-40",
            "unique_identifier":"062lCufCY0i5mI9NMTRUsF87XDq9ttYIonzZQjBcCOPvzoIJFOTSI6ZVNK9lMwy_iPFY2tuZzPY."
            "x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest"
        },
        "referrer":"https://ballard.amazon.com/OWA/",
        "referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade",
        "body":"contains some body data I want to manipulate",
        "method":"POST",
        "mode":"cors"
    }
).then(res => {console.log(res)})
```

This prints out something like this:

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "https://url/service.svc?action=FindConversation&ID=-40&AC=1", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: ReadableStream
locked: false
__proto__: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "https://url/OWA/service.svc?action=FindConversation&ID=-40&AC=1"
__proto__: Response
```

When I inspect the network request I just made, it looks like it isn't returning any JSON data, but responds with a `200` code. Is that normal?

I either expected it to return JSON data or fail.

Also, where would the JSON response data be in the `res`?

Comment: `fetch` returns a Promise that resolves to a request.  Call `.json()` on the request and it will return a Promise that resolves to an Object.

Comment: expanding on what @zero298 mentioned: ```.then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))``` are what the 2 promises will look like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal behavior. `fetch()` returns a [stream](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/) object and not just the body.

Use `res.json()` to extract the JSON content.
For non JSON responses, use `res.text()`

Comment: and if its HTML is in the return?

Comment: @MorganAllen OP Wanted JSON response. For HTML or non-JSON bodies, use `.text()`

Comment: @MorganAllen My apologies, I did not notice. Glad I helped 