# Node,Express response body is Readablestream instead of JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

Creating an API endpoint using Express. Usually responding with `res.json()` sends a JSON object in the response, which can consume in the client the same way.

I am using a batched promise in the API, resolving the promises (I think), and sending back an object.

Why is a JSON object not available client-side - instead I'm receiving a Readablestream in the body.

Below are the helper function and response, as well as what the client receives.

```
const addCoinVolumeData = async (data) => {
  const promises = data.map(async datum => {
    const volumeData = await fetchCoinGeckoCoinVolume(datum.id);
    const volumeDelta = calculateCoinVolumeDelta(volumeData);
    datum.volume_change_24h = volumeDelta;
    return datum;
  });

  const result = await Promise.all(promises);
  return result;
}
```

```
  data = await addCoinVolumeData(data);
  res.json(data);
```

```
Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:3001/aggregate-coin-data', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
```

Comment: [getting Fetch response data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460648/getting-fetch-response-data)

Comment: yeah thanks, as I mentioned res.json() is empty (I said not available but meant generally not satisfied).

res.text() returns generic HTML.

not sure why JSON is not being returned from Express.

Comment: are you sure you have the correct code on the client, it should look something like this: `fetch(..).then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>console.log(data))`

Comment: I'm using async/await. Turns out it was actually the URL was using to fetch client-side since calling 'localhost...'. Proxy in package.json didn't resolve much. Changed the port, and for some reason that worked - don't know why since nothing else running on it (as far as was reported anyway). All is well.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was actually the URL was using to fetch client-side since calling 'localhost...'. Proxy in package.json didn't resolve much. Changed the port, and for some reason that worked - don't know why since nothing else running on it (as far as was reported anyway). All is well.